# Is any alternate of Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, start-activity

I am creating Two activities as below now when click on button from MainActivity it shows SecondActivity and on click button from SecondActivity shows MainActivity normally but now on click soft back button Device show ANR.

MainActivity buttonClick -> SecondActivity buttonClick -> Soft back click , results ANR.

Is there any workaround?

This issue with Android 4.4.4. I know about this 
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63570#c2
issue.

Thanks for any help.

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        TextView tv;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            tv.setText("Main Activity");
        }

        public void onClickBtn(View view)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        public void finish(){
            Log.v("MainActivity", "Finish of main activity called");
            super.finish();
        }
    }


    public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
        TextView tv;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            tv.setText("Second Activity");
        }

        public void onClickBtn(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        public void finish(){
            Log.v("SecondActivity", "Finish of second activity called");
            super.finish();
        }
    }

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:onClick="onClickBtn"
        android:text="Button" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post the logcat please

Comment: thanks for help but its not work..(finish is just for show log)

Comment: @Aniruddha : nothing in logcat just show ANR Launcher isn't responding.

Comment: is there anything u r doing apart from posted above in activity?

Comment: try to use in your manifest file,
within activity tag  android:parentActivityName="your first Activity"

Comment: What should happen when user presses on back button? Your code is only that much?

Comment: @DIVA no, i just test this code on NEXUS 7 android 4.4.4

Comment: @Aniruddha when user presses on back button just close Activities one by one..

Comment: I've got the same behavior with Nexus 7 android version 5.0.2 and Nexus 5 android version 5.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

use `intent.setFlags (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);` the application will not crash.