# FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_TOP causing RuntimeException or black screen on rotation

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have two activities and I want to switch between them without re-creating or duplicating them. Each activity has a button that will send the user to the other using an intent with the FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_TOP.

This works great except for the following condition:

1. start the app fresh after a force close
2. hit the button to go to activity 2
3. hit the button to go back to activity 1
4. rotate the screen.

At this point the app crashes with "Performing stop of activity that is not resumed". Lollipop just shows a black screen.

Weirdly, if you go to the home screen before step 4 and resume the app and then rotate the above condition does not have any problem and the app works fine until it is closed/restarted.

This condition seems specific to FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_TOP and happens on Android 5.0 and 4.4 and only on a fresh start.

I have no attributes on the activities in the manifest. The layouts just have a button that calls a method that looks like this:

```
MainActivity:
public void goSecond(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        startActivity(i);
}

SecondActivity:
    public void goFirst(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

I am not overriding any other lifecycle methods or doing anything else.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting case, if you debug the lifecycle methods you can see that, as you rotate the screen, `onStop` is being called, with no `onPause` before. The crash then logs

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing pause of activity that is not resumed: MainActivity
```

followed by

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: MainActivity
```

I suppose it’s a bug in the framework. Interestingly this only seem to occur with the flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`.

As of writing I just found this post, which clearly shows that there seems to be a major flaw with this flag: [Is any alternate of Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25306473/is-any-alternate-of-intent-flag-activity-reorder-to-front) (notice the mentioned Android Bug Ticket)

---

**Workaround:**
If you are dependend on the behaviour `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` gives you, and you want to mimic it (sort of), you could use

```
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

instead (however, it works slightly differently - it clears stack on top of called activity, instead of reordering it, so you would have at least 1 re-creation of activity).

Another option is to play around with `launchMode` attribute in the activity's definition in the manifest. `launchMode="singleInstance"` could be what you're after (however this messes with your task stack, so handle with caution)

After all, if your design allows it, consider fragments to avoid those issues altogether.